# How to use utf8mb4 symbols in program which stored in varchar field in mysql without changing mysql's field

Tags: java, php, mysql

I want to use emoji in fields which stored in DB like **VARCHAR** type. And I can't change DB encoding to **utf8mb4** because column which I need to set is used in full text indexing (5 columns are indexed including the column with **TEXT** format). If I change encoding to **utf8mb4** it won't be supported by indexes (because this field will take more bytes than can be used for indexing ). How can I do it?

Comment: Table really big and ALTER TABLE would work long period of time, so changing encoding to utf8mb4 doesn't fit. Can you answer if here is some alternatives?

Comment: What encoding is the column currently defined with?

Comment: Now I use UTF-8

Comment: How big is your table?

Comment: Can you help explain this part? 'it won't be supported by indexes (because this field will take more bytes than can be used for indexing )'?

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the table charset is the right way to go (if I fully understand the situation). I see you're worried about how long `alter table` would take. Then how about creating a new table of the appropriate specs, and using `insert into` from the current one? Then once you've confirmed that the data transferred properly, you could drop the original table and rename the new one.